# Pandas wont concat new dataframe to csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to make a program where I have a already existing csv file where I seek to be able to add data several times over. However even though I don't get any error messeges and I don't get the file updated with additional data.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import csv 
from faker import Faker`your text`
import random

fake = Faker()


with open('recources2.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(["Name", "Attack", "Defence", "Consumption"])
        writer.writerow([fake.name(), 20, 12, 7])
        file.close()



def soldierGeneration(x):

    for i in range (0,x):
        attackValue = random.randint(0,21)
        defenceValue = random.randint(0,21)
        consumptionValue = random.randint(0,11)
        df = pd.read_csv('recources2.csv')
        Soldier = pd.DataFrame([fake.name(), attackValue, defenceValue, consumptionValue])
        pd.concat([df, Soldier], ignore_index=True)
        
        
soldierGeneration(4)
```

I tried changing the entire concat line into a seperate variable:

```
hf = pd.concat([df, Soldier], ignore_index=True) 
print(hf)
```

From this I got another output which also isn't the way I want it to stay and even the output alone looks really weird:

```
             Name  Attack  Defence  Consumption             0
0  Kevin Gutierrez    20.0     12.0          7.0           NaN
1              NaN     NaN      NaN          NaN  Thomas Adams
2              NaN     NaN      NaN          NaN             8
3              NaN     NaN      NaN          NaN             4
4              NaN     NaN      NaN          NaN             3
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the incorrect format of `Soldier` (one long column instead of a single row with correct headers).

You should change:

```
Soldier = pd.DataFrame([fake.name(), attackValue, defenceValue, consumptionValue])
```

To:

```
Soldier = pd.DataFrame([[fake.name(), attackValue, defenceValue, consumptionValue]],
                       columns=['Name', 'Attack', 'Defence', 'Consumption'])
```

Or:

```
Soldier = pd.DataFrame({'Name': [fake.name()],
                        'Attack': [attackValue],
                        'Defense': [defenceValue],
                        'Consumption': [consumptionValue]})
```

Comment: Thank you! Had tried changing it into a dictionary but missed the it being list within it.

Comment: It is how ever still not saving the data to the csv file for later use, is there anyway i can fix this on the small scale or do i need to restructure the code completely?